# Data doesn't show in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

First of all I want to apologize for my bad English :)

I am having a problem with AngularJS, when I want to load a modal from datagrid.

Here is my code for the grid:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit track by $index">
                    <td>{{data.lastName}} {{data.firstName}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.phoneNumber}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.cityID}}</td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="show(data.id)">DETAILS</button></td>
```

Modal code :

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title"><strong>{{row.firstName}} {{row.lastName}}</strong> Details</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover info-table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Email:</td>
          <td>{{row.email}}</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

and JS code:

```
$scope.show = function (id) { 
    $http.get('inc/getDetails.php?id='+id).
    success(function(data) {
      $scope.row = data;
      $('#det-modal').modal('show');

    });

};
```

The modal is loading, but does not load the data.

Comment: strongly suggest getting rid of `bootstrap.js` and switching to `angular-ui-bootstrap`

Comment: Have you checked data in the response? Place a breakpoint in the browser developer console at the "$scope.row = data;" row, and see if data it's in the format that you expect (it must be an object in the format {firstName:"Name", lastName:"LastName", email:"email@....com"})

Comment: While calling jquery in controllers it's not the correct way to use angularjs, i think this is not the reason of the problem. A JsFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/8wf17mmg/ shows that it works, even if not "conceptually" correct.

Comment: @StefanoCastriotta thanks i will see code now ...
data are in good format, json ...

Comment: And what do you mean with "but does not load the data"? Do you see blank values or the angularjs placeholders? ({{row.email}}). Where is the modal div placed? (it must be inside the "ng-controller", otherwise it's out of scope)

Comment: "data are in good format, json" with format i mean that your row object must not be "wrapped" inside another property, eg: { result: {firstName:"Name", lastName:"LastName", email:"email@....com" ...}}.

Comment: @StefanoCastriotta .. data not load, i mean there is nothing to se ...
when i go to inspect element :
<td>Email:</td>
<td class="ng-binding"></td>

Yes, it`s inside ng-controller

when i go to inc/getDetails.php?id=15 i got this array:    [{"id":"15","firstName":"Milos","lastName":"Petrovic","email":"petrovic.n.milos@gmail.com"}]

Comment: So it's an array you get? Then you have to assign the first element:  $scope.row = data[0];

Comment: @StefanoCastriotta  WOW, it`s work now ... Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome ;) But anyway, you should use the angular-ui-bootstrap as said by other users.

Answer (score 0):

The code would not work because the **row** variable is out of scope when the modal is invoked as its in non-angular world.

You should not access the DOM element directly in controller so the following line should not be used in angular world.

```
 $('#det-modal').modal('show');
```

To fix the issue consider using https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ which would enable you to pass in the row as a scope variable.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i will try that way ... just to firure how :)